# Has anyone used the pi to send SMS/MMS messages?

Tags: home-automation, communication

As part of my project, I'd like to send an image to a phone number.

I understand I can achieve this quite easily with e-mail, but I'd like to pursue the MMS route first.  I've looked around online but can't find any useful information.

Has anyone done this?  The MMS's will be sent to a UK number if that has any bearing on my choices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service that is connected to the GSM network. You use a simple API to send SMS messages or attach MMS images. The rates are fair.

I use [TextLocal in UK](http://www.textlocal.com/simple-developer-sms-api) and you can send messages to the world. There are allot of other service providers available too.

Simple PHP to send a text message

```
<?php
    // Textlocal account details
$username = urlencode('youremail@address.com');
    // Get this when logged in at https://control.txtlocal.co.uk/docs/
$hash = urlencode('Your API hash');
    // Message details
$numbers = urlencode(447123456789,447987654321);
$sender = urlencode('Textlocal');
$message = urlencode('This is your message');

    // Prepare data for POST request
$data = 'username=' . $username . '&hash=' . $hash
     . '&numbers=' . $numbers . "&sender=" . $sender . "&message=" . $message;
    // Send the GET request with cURL
$ch = curl_init('https://api.txtlocal.com/send/?' . $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
    // Process your response here
echo $response;
?>
```

- [MMS API](http://www.textlocal.com/sending-multi-media-messages-api)

Comment: You could also use SMS Pi if you are in the UK. http://www.smspi.co.uk/ which, unlike TextLocal in UK, it is free.

Comment: Freeeee? How is this possible?

Comment: I don't know, maybe it's black magic! :D

Comment: Nah its just for playing around and funded by donations. You cant really send SMS without being connected to the GSM network and definitely not for free.

Comment: I run smspi and am happy to give free accounts for any raspberry pi projects. The site breaks even so I can afford to give free accounts. Twitter: @smspiuk
Email: info@smapi.co.UK